# SetWindowsHookEx failing with google chrome. Error code 87 invalid parameter

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, setwindowshookex

I am making a tutorial based program and want to be able to hook my code into certain apps to get the tutorial interacting with the app.

My hook code works for most apps except google chrome. I have stripped my code down to the following so you can see it going wrong.

Main.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>

unsigned long GetProcId( const std::string& name )
{
    unsigned long res = 0 ;

    HANDLE hSnapShot=CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);
    PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo ;
    processInfo.dwSize=sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);

    if( !Process32First( hSnapShot, &processInfo ) )
    {
        CloseHandle( hSnapShot ); 
        return res ;
    }

    do 
    {
        if( NULL != ( strstr ( strlwr ( processInfo.szExeFile ), name.c_str() ) ) )
        {               
            res = processInfo.th32ProcessID ;
            break ;
        }
    } while(Process32Next( hSnapShot,&processInfo ));

    CloseHandle( hSnapShot ) ;
    return res ;
}

typedef LRESULT (CALLBACK *DllHookProc)(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
               LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    unsigned int processid = GetProcId( "chrome.exe" ) ;

    if (processid == 0)
    {
        return 0 ;
    }

    HINSTANCE dllInstance = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll") ;

    if (dllInstance == NULL)
    {
        return 0 ;
    }

    DllHookProc hookProc = (DllHookProc)::GetProcAddress(dllInstance, "HookProc");

    if ( hookProc == NULL) 
    {
        FreeLibrary(dllInstance);
        return 0 ;
    }

    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC,(HOOKPROC)hookProc,
        dllInstance, processid );

    if (hook == NULL)
    {
        FreeLibrary(dllInstance);
        return 0 ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Test Dll (mydll.dll)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc (int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    //Pass to the next chain in the process list
    return CallNextHookEx( 0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Definition file

```
LIBRARY "MYDLL"
EXPORTS
HookProc @1
```

Everything works fine (including getting processId and loading library and getprocaddress) up to the SetWindowsHookEx which returns NULL with error code 87 (invalid parameter).

Both `chrome.exe` and my code are 32 bit.

Does this work for anyone else or does anyone know what it doesnt work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible problem would be if you're building 64bit code, but `chrome.exe` is 32bit (or the other way around). [See comment & update, this is not the case.]

---

One suspicious thing in your code is that you're not calling [`Process32First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and that seems to be required. See for ex: [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

Last suggestion: you're passing in a process id to `SetWindowsHookEx`, but that expects a thread id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but they are both 32 bit

Comment: Good spot with the Process32First. Ive fixed the code but unfortunately still the same problem. Thanks again

Comment: That solved it thanks very much! However chrome potentially has lots of threads running, so is there a way I can find the main GUI threadid so I know my dll wont be unloaded until they exit chrome? Thanks again you've been a great help

Comment: Sorry, don't know about that - I don't actually code on windows :-) Ask a separate question.

Comment: Also, please consider reading this: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my answer was of any help.

Comment: "However chrome potentially has lots of threads running, so is there a way I can find the main GUI threadid" - best thing to do is find the HWND within Chrome that you are interested in, and use GetWindowThreadProcessId to get the threadId of that. Also recommend using Spy++ to check out how the windows are structured and which process/threads own them - but be aware that Chrome could change how it works at some stage in future. For now, it looks as though all HWNDs in chrome are owned by the same thread, with the exception of some plugin windows.

Answer (score 2):

You realize that chrome uses a multi-process model, right?  There are many chrome instances cooperating, and some of them might not have an event queue.

Most certainly your `GetProcId` code is not going to work for chrome because it only finds one matching process.